# Why Can I Not Suspend Binding on a BindingSource?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datatable

First, the offending code:

```
public virtual void grid_RefreshFetchData(Object sender, RefreshEventArgs e)
{
    C1DBGrid g = (C1DBGrid)sender;
    if (g.RefreshUseResult)
    {
        DataTable dtNew = FetchRawData(e.Argument);
        dt_Patch(dtNew, e.Argument);
        g.BindingSource.SuspendBinding();
        ((DataTable)g.BindingSource.DataSource).Clear();
        ((DataTable)g.BindingSource.DataSource).Merge(dtNew);
        g.BindingSource.ResumeBinding();
    }
}
```

What you see is an event handler that is being called from a background thread that is ultimately launched because a Windows form wants data.  The grid object (it's a ComponentOne TrueDBGrid) is owned by that form, and we have events set up to allow the form to tell the grid to ask for new data.  That call leads to this handler, whose purpose is to request an underlying data class to fetch a DataTable with records, and then to merge that table with the grid's BindingSource (which is a DataTable of the same schema).

My problem:  when the Merge() method is called to merge new data into the grid's (newly emptied) BindingSource (again, a DataTable itself), a massive series of exceptions is being thrown.  Each exception instance is really a triad of exceptions:  one System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException followed by a pair of System.InvalidOperationExceptions.  This results in incredibly poor performance, and this is what I must remedy.

I understand what is happening.  On the form, we are binding TextBox controls to the grid's BindingSource using the control's Text property.  This binding is being fired every time a row is merged into the BindingSource.  That last part has not been observed, it's a bit of a guess, but the sheer quantity of exceptions suggests it is the correct assumption.  That, and the fact that when I commented out all of the binding, the performance increased dramatically.

So what I am asking for is help understanding how I can suspend this binding trigger.  As you can see, I have lines in the event handler that attempt to suspend it on the BindingSource.

I have already tried this as well:

```
g.SuspendBinding();
```

It made no difference.  In fact, I have tried suspending the binding on both ends of the equation, in the form and in the threaded refresh, but always all attempts have been fruitless.

Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

This may be your problem (Taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.suspendbinding.aspx)).

> Using SuspendBinding and prevents changes from being pushed into the
>   data source until ResumeBinding is called, but does not actually
>   prevent any events from occurring. Controls that use complex data
>   binding, such as the DataGridView control, update their values based
>   on change events such as the ListChanged event, so calling
>   SuspendBinding will not prevent them from receiving changes to the
>   data source. For this reason, this SuspendBinding and ResumeBinding
>   are designed for use with simple-bound controls, such as the TextBox
>   control. Alternatively you can use these methods in a complex binding
>   scenario if you suppress ListChanged events by setting the
>   RaiseListChangedEvents property to false.

Comment: I came across that as well, and I wonder the same.  Perhaps it is.  Hopefully, someone who knows more than I can confirm that for me based on what I've described.  Although, the "simple-bound controls" part does fit what I am doing.  My binding looks like this:  txtEquipment.DataBindings.Add("Text", gridMain.BindingSource, "fldEquipNo");

Comment: @DonBoitnott, I feel your pain. I've gone through smilar things to this before and often resort to getting rid of binding altogether because I have events firing off all over the place. (Think cartoon character in a room full of mousetraps, step on one and it triggers a horrible chain reaction!)

Comment: Dang, that would be rough.  We have something on the order of 50 forms, all with binding to at least one owned grid.  That would be awful.  Perhaps insurmountable...we're not a big outfit.  I considered perhaps setting up a delegate that could be fired when I need to "suspend", and that delegate could do something to the controls.  Maybe store the bindings, delete them, and replace them after the refresh completes?  Seems like such a hack...but what else could I do?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the hack approach does seem to succeed quite well.  I don't really like it, but I also don't see any alternative approach that doesn't involve full-spectrum control of binding manually.

I have the luxury of having all of my Windows Forms based upon a class we derived from Form.  So in there, I have crafted two methods:  SuspendBinding() and ResumeBinding().

Here's a sample of what I did:

```
private List<KeyValuePair<String, Binding>> _savedBindings = new List<KeyValuePair<String, Binding>>();

private delegate void InvokeSuspendBinding();
public void SuspendBinding()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new InvokeSuspendBinding(SuspendBinding));
        return;
    }

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in ChildControls)
    {
        if (entry.Value is Control && ((Control)entry.Value).DataBindings.Count > 0)
        {
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < ((Control)entry.Value).DataBindings.Count; i++)
            {
                _savedBindings.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, Binding>(entry.Key as String, ((Control)entry.Value).DataBindings[i]));
                ((Control)entry.Value).DataBindings.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
}

private delegate void InvokeResumeBinding();
public void ResumeBinding()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new InvokeResumeBinding(ResumeBinding));
        return;
    }

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in ChildControls)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Binding> kvp2 in _savedBindings)
        {
            if (kvp2.Key.Equals(entry.Key))
                ((Control)entry.Value).DataBindings.Add(kvp2.Value);
        }
    }

    _savedBindings.Clear();
}
```

Note that the member ChildControls referenced in the loops is a member of our form class and it is the result of a recursive loop that returns a Hashtable of control names and Control objects.